# built-in data type conversion to user defined data type c++

Tags: c++

My question is regarding data type conversion in c++. Does c++ provides a implicit conversion for built-in data types ( int, float) to user defined data types?

In the following example, I am trying to add a double ( t4 = t3 + 1.0) with test object type and its working fine using + operator so is the double implicitly converted to test type object?

```c++
class test {
    double d;
    int m;

    public:
    test() {
        d=0;
        m=0;
    }

    test(double n) {
        d=n;
    }

    const test operator+(const test& t) {
        test temp;
        temp.d = d+ t.d;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main() {
    test t1(1.2);
    test t2(2.5);
    test t3, t4;
    t3= t1+ t2;
    t4 = t3 + 1.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code [does not compile](http://ideone.com/gdhVO), because your class `test` does not have any constructor, yet you call one in `test t1(1.2)`. Please post real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor `test(double n)` declares an implicit conversion from `double` to `test`. In general, any constructor that is callable with exactly one argument (that includes constructors that can take more arguments, but have default-values for those), can be used as an implicit conversion, unless it is marked `explicit`:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x); // implicit conversion from int to Foo
    explicit Foo(char c); // marked explicit - no implicit conversion
    Foo(std::string a, double pi = 3.14159); // can be used as implicit 
                                             // conversion due to default 
                                             // argument
};
```

**Edit:** `t4 = 1.0 + t3` does not work, because you have overloaded your `operator+` as a member-function, and thus it is only considered if the first operand is of the type `test` - implicit conversion are not tried in this case. To make this work, make your operator a free function:

```
test operator+(const test& lhs, const test& rhs);
```

Comment: ok.. but then why t4 = 1.0 + t3 doesn't work? shouldn't it be converted implicitly  like: t4 = test(1.0) + t3;

Comment: Edited my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your constructor `test(double)` is not explicit

```
// implicite convertible
test(double n)
{
  d=n;
}

// not implicite convertible
explicit test(double n)
{
  d=n;
}
```